# What is the difference between members and fiels in archunit

Tags: archunit

I wondering what's the difference between `members()` and `fields()` in ArchUnit. I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ArchUnit User Guide](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_domain) documents the domain model.
The [members](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaMember.html) of a class consist of all of its [fields](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaField.html) and [code units](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaCodeUnit.html) (i.e. [methods](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaMethod.html), [constructors](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaConstructor.html) and [static initializers](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaStaticInitializer.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, no idea why two people didn't saw it :-/

Answer (score 2):

I look into the code and the answer is very simple:

- fields are what expected the fields of a class
- methods are the methods
- constructors are the constructors

and member is the union of all this lists.